# Is moving between iOS subviews within a single view possible without returning to the view?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is moving between iOS subviews within a single view possible without returning to the view? If so, how? Code example welcome.

How I'm doing it now but this requires returning to the "home" view:
In the myFile.m

```
// Define the other views

DF_Results                  *df_Results;
CR_FiringRange              *cr_FiringRange;
CR_AssetLoader              *cr_AssetLoader;

DB_GeneralData              *db_GeneralData;
DB_ArmorData                *db_ArmorData;
DB_WeaponsData              *db_WeaponsData;



@synthesize ScreenButton01;
@synthesize ScreenButton02;

@synthesize ScreenButton03;
@synthesize ScreenButton04;

@synthesize ScreenButton05;
@synthesize ScreenButton06;
@synthesize ScreenButton07;
.
.
.

-(IBAction) ScreenButton02Clicked:(id) sender {
    df_Results = [[DF_Results alloc]
                               initWithNibName:@"DF_Results"
                               bundle:nil];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:df_Results.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

In DF_Results to return we tap another button but I would like to be able to jump straight to another subview:

```
-(IBAction) ResultsScreenButton01Clicked:(id) sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: If you would like a little more flair, but without a navigationController, try [self presentModalViewController animated:BOOL];  that will let you specify an animation like a flip easily.  Google modal view transitions to see what I mean.

Comment: @CodaFi switching between modal view controllers is not much fun. Getting one to close, and another to open in the same action is fiddly and messy in my experience.

Comment: @KennyWinker Oh?  It's always worked beautifully for me.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4.0 UIView has a number of block based animation transitions tasks which according to docs are the recommended approach. E.g. this one could be useful:

```
(void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

See UIView docs for more details.